# yarn workspaces and docker

Tags: docker, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to use yarn workspaces and then put my application into a Docker 
image.

The folder structure looks like this:

- root

  - Dockerfile
  - node_modules/

    - libA --> ../libA
  - libA/

    - ...
  - app/

    - ...

Unfortunately Docker doesn't support symbolic links - therefore it is not possible to copy the node_modules-folder in the root directory into a Docker image, even if the Dockerfile is in the root as in my case.

One thing I could do would be to exclude the symlinks with .dockerignore and then copy the real directory to the image.

Another idea - which I would prefer - would be to have a tool that replaces the symlinks with the actual contents of the symlink. Do you know if there is such a tool (preferably a Javascript package)?

Thanks

Comment: Should you not be using `yarn install` to install the node modules in the Docker container environment, rather than copying them from your development environment? This can be set up in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Oh right - didn't think of that possibility. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool! If you need further help I can put it as an answer, otherwise I'm sure you'll come right with a bit of research on the above.

Comment: I got it working with your answer :-)

Comment: Glad it helped! I've extended my explanation above and included it as an answer for anyone else who has the same issue. Would appreciate it if you accepted it, no obligation to do so.

Comment: I guess libA is published to npmjs repository. What if you do not want to publish libA?

Comment: @GudlaugurEgilsson I've been looking for this exact answer for a long time :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yarn is used for dependency management, and should be configured to run within the Docker container to install the necessary dependencies, rather than copying them from your local machine.

The major benefit of Docker is that it allows you to recreate your development environment without worrying about the machine that it is running on - the same thing applies to Yarn, by running `yarn install` it installs the right versions for the relevant architecture of the machine your Docker image is built upon.

In your **Dockerfile** include the following after configuring your work directory:

```
RUN yarn install
```

Then you should be all sorted!

Another thing you should do is include the ***node_modules*** directory in your ***.gitignore*** and ***.dockerignore*** files so it is never include when distributing your code.

**TL;DR:** Don't copy ***node_modules*** directory from local machine, include `RUN yarn install` in Dockerfile

Comment: But the `yarn.lock` is in the root, and not in the sub project, so we can get unexpected upgrades to dependencies, which will cause all kinds of mayhem (current problem I'lm trying to fix).

Comment: Using the Docker build context you can run your Docker build from the root, for a sub-project. Then you can pull in whatever files (such as `yarn.lock`) that you need.

Comment: @ChrisKemp Did you find a fix to this problem?

Comment: No.  I opted for not sharing the common node_modules and had each sub-project manage its own.